# Dataframe to JSON of a particular format - Python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have the following data frame

```
         lat        long                                         batchItems
0  64.427482 -161.457786  {"query": "?query=64.42748213233087,-161.45778...
1  31.271877  130.331371           {"query": "?query=31.271877,130.331371"}
```

which I need in the following format

```
{
    "batchItems": [
        {"query": "?query=64.42748213233087,-161.45778592219781"},
        {"query": "?query=31.271877,130.331371"}
    ]
}
```

using the inbuilt to_json method in pandas gives me unwanted backslashes ("{") which get rejected by the API i'm trying to post this to. I don't need the lat and long fields.

Comment: So `batchItems` is `dict`  or `str` (seems to be `str` regarding the double quotes) ?

Comment: `{"batchItems": df.batchItems.apply(ast.literal_eval).to_list()}`? Skip the `apply` if they are already dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `batchItems` is `str` type, so if you go to JSON, it's normal that quotes are escaped because they are not delimiting some string, they are inside the content itself.

You may change the type to `dict` using `json.loads`, then get the column as a `list`

```
import json
result = {"batchItems": df['batchItems'].apply(json.loads).tolist()}
print(result)  # {'batchItems': [{'query': '?query=64,-161'}, {'query': '?query=31,130'}]}
```

Comment: thanks, it is a str like you deduced. This answer works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

`df[['batchItems']].to_dict(orient='list')` will return a dictionary in the required format

```
{
    "batchItems": [
        {"query": "?query=64.42748213233087,-161.45778592219781"},
        {"query": "?query=31.271877,130.331371"}
    ]
}
```

You have to send this dictionary to the function that sends the data to the external API.